# Ajax call to Code-Behind not working before browser close event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, silverlight

I am working on a Silverlight 4.0 In-browser Application. I need to bring up a pop-up on click of the Close(Cross button or Alt+F4) Event. As the Close Event happens on the local browser, so none of server side events are getting triggered on the Close event. I was trying to use **OnBeforeUnload** Event of JavaScript on the Default.aspx file as mentioned below:

```
    function areYouSure() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "default.aspx/GetDialogStatus",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d)
                {
                    confMessage = "Unsaved Changes error message";
                }
                else {
                    confMessage = nochanges;
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }

        });

        return confMessage;
    }

    var areYouReallySure = false;         
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
    });
```

For the Code Behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool GetDialogStatus()
    {
        if(**Business Condition Satisfies**)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When checking on the local environment the code just works fine. But, when deployed to the Dev, Test Servers, the pop-up is not coming up and we are getting seeing an authentication pop-up when the ajax call happens. Can anybody have faced similar issue?

Comment: You mean, OnBeforeUnload is not working when the code is deployed on server?

Comment: OnBeforeUnload event is working, but the ajax call inside the OnBeforeUnload event is not able to call the code behind webmethod. When the debugger crosses the $.ajax code it gives me an authentication pop-up. In case I do not use $.ajax, then  OnBeforeUnload just works fine.